# getjson response returns null in phonegap (android)

Tags: android, json, jquery-mobile, cordova, android-emulator

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/v1/message", 

  function(data) {
    console.log(data);
      alert("message"+data);//this alert stmt is displayed it means that 
              the service call is getting executed 
    });
```

service method

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,
        value = "/message" )
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public String message()
{
    return "jasdknsd";

 }
```

I am getting response of this call as null please help me out if I am doing something wrong in the service method and I have both of them in same network because of which I am not using callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connection to localhost is not supported.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=133

`127.0.0.1` is the emulated system's own loopback interface, not the one running on
your host development machine.

within the Android system, one should use `10.0.2.2` which is an alias specifically
setup to contact your host `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

use `10.0.2.2` instead of `localhost:8080`

Comment: do I have to configure this any where since I am unable to call the service and even getting alert message

Comment: i am able to call the service if i use 10.0.2.2:8080 instead of just 10.0.2.2 and I am not getting the response back can you please help me out but can see in server logs that I am able to call the service